# Merge rows with same identifier columsn (PANDAS)

Tags: python, pandas

i want to combine rows that have the same id and variant. this is my expected input and output
how can i do this in pandas?
input:

```
id company tag              variant
1  Adobe   ['hello','bye']  B
1  Adobe   ['gary,'tom']    B
1  Adobe   ['tim','john']   A
1  Adobe   ['fries,'salad'] A
```

output:

```
id company tag                                variant
1  Adobe   ['hello','bye'],[['gary,'tom']]    B
1  Adobe   [['tim','john'],['fries,'salad']]  A
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? please post your code

Comment: i've tried `df.groupby(['id','variant'],as_index=False,sort=False).last()`, but it only gives me the last record. kidn of stuck.

Answer (score 2):

#### `agg`

```
df.groupby(['id', 'variant'], as_index=False).agg({'company': 'first', 'tag': list})

   id variant company                            tag
0   1       A   Adobe  [[tim, john], [fries, salad]]
1   1       B   Adobe    [[hello, bye], [gary, tom]]
```